# use BASIC authentication with client certificate authentication

Tags: http, authentication, ssl

Is it possible, in general, for a server to require both client certificate authentication and BASIC authentication?

For example, an intranet site of some sort, which requires :

- The machine to have a specific certificate installed (client cert authentication), AND
- A valid user to log in (basic authentication)

NOTE: this question isn't about a server supporting one or the other, but both together (as in the requester must authenticate both ways)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have both. The client certificate will be verified during the TLS handshake while basic authentication will be done at the HTTP level, i.e. inside the TLS connection after the TLS handshake is done and the client certificate checked.